# Passing Information and going back in XIB iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have three Xibs (`A`, `B`, `C`). From `A` I am going to `B`. So If I have to pass data to `A` and get back to `A`, I have written a delegate and I am dismissing the Controller. This is fine.

But now my requirements are that I have to go from `A` to `B` and from `B` to `C`. Now from `C` I have to pass data to `A` and come back to `A`.
How to do this?

Note: I am not using `StoryBoard` or Navigation Controller. And Controller A is not root View Controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotificationCenter for passing data from viewcontroller to another view controllers.
You can try NSNotificationCenter as shown below,

Example:

In your ViewControllerA.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataReceived:) name:@"passData" object:nil];
}

-(void)dataReceived:(NSNotification *)noti
{
    NSLog(@"dataReceived :%@", noti.object);
}
```

In your ViewControllerC.m

```
-(void)gotoHome
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"passData" object:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Sample Data" forKey:@"dataDic"]];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Check this example in below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501709/5349267

Comment: I have not used navigation controller. And Controller A is not root View Controller

Comment: instead of  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; write your code for navigation to viewController A

Answer (score 0):

Add **a notification observer** with a name in **controller A**, **Then from where you want to send data** (in your case B, C), From there **post a notification** with **the name you are observing** in controller A.

Answer (score 0):

I extend the answer of [Sommm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40817398/918337) as it is my wish to underline how important

> MVC, the model-view-controller pattern,

as a design pattern in iOS as well as macOS applications really is and how useful it is if one obeys to it.

**Good solution:** Use `NSNotificationCenter` in order to let parts of your application communicate that don't know about each other usually. You register controllers that are waiting for information as observers for a specific message type and then post from other parts of your code what should be sent to the observers (using the specific message type the observers are waiting for).

---

**Much better solution:** Don't use `NSNotificationCenter` and instead design your application better and obey to the `MVC` design pattern.

The OP's initial question somehow shows (at least to my mind) a common misunderstanding: Don't try to create a specific UI flow and write your code accordingly but think of your application in a more general way first. As you don't give enough information on the question what you *really* want to do, I will assume you are generating an instance of a class `User` in your three `XIBs` called `A`, `B` and `C`.

1. Model: Write a class `User` that has the needed properties like `firstname`, `surname` and `email`
2. Controller: Write a controller `UserController` that holds an array of every instance of the class `User` that exists in your application.
3. View: Now (and only now!) think about your `View`. First question: Do you really need three `XIBs` or could you use one with three `UIViews`? The views could be `IBOutlets` of a class say `UserViewController`. Make this class the delegate of your single `XIB` file and connect the `IBOutlets`. Your `UserViewController` could then have a property `user` of the instance of `User` it represents and set the properties of `user` according to what has been inserted in the `UITextFields` for example.

If this is too complicated to you, you can use the `NSNotificationCenter` in order to send messages (with content if needed) between different parts of your application. If you find yourself using it very often: increased usage of this technique usually is a sign of a badly constructed application that needs some refactoring.